# Groovy qSort and Filter implementations giving stack overflow error

Tags: function, recursion, groovy, functional-programming, stack-overflow

This is the implementation of filter in Groovy I am attempting to use.

```
def filter(list, p) {
    if (list.size() == 0) { return list }
    if (p(list.head())) {
        [] + list.head() + filter(list.tail(), p)
    } else {
        filter(list.tail(), p)
    }
}
```

This is the implementation of a Quick Sort algorithm I am attempting to use.

```
def qSort(list) {
    if ( list.size() <= 1 ) {
        return list
    } else {
        def pivot = list[(int)list.size() / 2]
        def sorted = []
        sorted += qSort(filter(list, { it < pivot}))
        sorted += qSort(filter(list, { it == pivot})) 
        sorted += qSort(filter(list, { it > pivot })) 
    }
}
```

This is the list I am trying to sort, relatively arbitrary.

```
def list = [5, 3, 2, 1, 8, 4, 5, 8, 23, 4, 6, 8, 3, 23, 76, 8, 9, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2]
```

I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.Math.getExponent(Math.java:1310)
at java.lang.StrictMath.floorOrCeil(StrictMath.java:355)
at java.lang.StrictMath.ceil(StrictMath.java:321)
at java.lang.Math.ceil(Math.java:405)
at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:1608)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.BigDecimalMath.divideImpl(BigDecimalMath.java:62)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.IntegerMath.divideImpl(IntegerMath.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgmimpl.NumberNumberDiv$NumberNumber.invoke(NumberNumberDiv.java:320)
```

Comment: `(int)(list.size() / 2)`.  size is already an int.  or just `list.size()>>1`

Comment: Changing that does not do anything, if I remove the type cast to int I get `Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.getAt() is applicable for argument types: (java.math.BigDecimal) values: [11] `

Comment: what groovy version is this?  the stackoverflow is in the code, but not for a cast/divide/... problem with 2.4.

Comment: `sorted += qSort(filter(list, { it == pivot}))` -- line causing the problem

Comment: Looks the code is working fine if there is no duplicate elements. So code needs to be handled if there are duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

It gets bogged down when you have a list of `n` numbers (where `n > 1`) that are all equal to the pivot.

If you change:

```
if ( list.size() <= 1 ) {
```

To:

```
if ( list.unique(false).size() <= 1 ) {
```

It will work...there may be a less "hacky feeling" solution though

Comment: Simple and perfect change.